# SH script string concatenation not working

Tags: sh

I have a bash script I'm writing that is not concatenating a string as expected. I have (in the script) a preset list of folder paths in a single string, separated by a single space. This works great, later on in the script, I can cycle through each folder path as expected.

I am trying to allow the user to enter in an optional list of other folders, and add to the list of paths to check for. Below is my code, and the output of the command:

```
#!/bin/sh
MOUNTPOINTS="/ /var /var/moodledata2"   #Set the mount points to check for

while getopts ":dh" opt; do
        case $opt in
                d)
                        DEBUG=true
                        ;;
                h)
                        echo USAGE: diskspace \[-d\] \[\/path1 ...\]
                        exit 0
                        ;;
                \?)
                        echo Incorrect syntax
                        ;;
        esac
        shift $((OPTIND - 1))
done

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        for var in $@; do
                NEWMOUNTPOINTS .= $var
                echo "${MOUNTPOINTS} ${var}"
                echo "${NEWMOUNTPOINTS}"
        done
fi
```

When running the command...

```
$ ./dt /home
./dt: 22: ./dt: NEWMOUNTPOINTS: not found
/ /var /var/moodledata2 /home
```

I originally tried with `MOUNTPOINTS .= ${var}` and `MOUNTPOINTS .= "${var}"`, but they still produce the same error. I thought I could create a new variable, but that didn't work either (as shown above). The rest of the script continues on, but only with the original `MOUNTPOINTS` at the top; it never changes that, even if I use `MOUNTPOINTS .= $var`, above.

**What can I do to get a dynamic string created with the command line arguments supplied?**

Comment: I'm not sure `shift`ing like that **in** the `while` loop is actually working the way you expect. I think you want to do that *after* the loop is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NEWMOUNTPOINTS="${NEWMOUNTPOINTS} ${var} "
```

This should concatenate the variable.

Comment: This isn't working for me, for some reason it only uses the second var

Comment: Im doing a="${first}${second}"
b="${first} ${second}"
c="$first $second"
d="$first"
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
echo $d and the only one that uses first is d

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings, do:

```
            NEWMOUNTPOINTS+=" ${var}"
```

It currently executes a command/function named `NEWMOUNTPOINTS` and passes `.= $var` arguments to it.

Comment: ./dt: 26: ./dt: NEWMOUNTPOINTS+= /home: not found

Comment: Is that error coming from the code you posted? In your code, 26th line is `fi` but the error shows that you are executing something.

Comment: Sorry, I removed some redundant points from my script - The line it stops on is the line where `NEWMOUNTPOINTS` is executing.

Comment: Looks like you are not actually using `bash` but `sh` (as indicated by your shebang). In that case, use the method suggested by jftuga. Concatenation using `+=` doesn't work in `sh`.

Comment: You're right, using `sh`. Retagged question, but thanks very much for your help